# ZSH prints the command I ran before showing the output

Tags: command-line, bash, terminal, zsh, oh-my-zsh

I'm using OhMyZsh with the PowerLevel9K theme and ZSH always prints the command I ran first (just the command without the arguments) before actually showing the output:

```bash
$ ls
ls<dir1> <dir2> <dir3>
```

- I have been facing this issue for a long time, so maybe it's a feature, and haven't been able to find any way to disable this, even after googling around a lot; perhaps there's a name for this feature and I'm using the incorrect terminology? 
   I want to disable this so that it works like Bash, where I just see the output of the command:

  ```bash
  $ ls
  <dir1> <dir2> <dir3>...
  ```

How do I resolve this?

- [`powerlevel9k.zsh-theme`](https://github.com/Powerlevel9k/powerlevel9k/blob/master/powerlevel9k.zsh-theme) 
   *(default is used and is too large to include as text)*
- `.zshrc`:

  ```bash
  export ZSH="/home/anish/.oh-my-zsh"
  export TERM=screen-256color

  POWERLEVEL9K_MODE='awesome-fontconfig'
  ZSH_THEME="powerlevel9k/powerlevel9k"

  POWERLEVEL9K_CONTEXT_TEMPLATE='%n'
  POWERLEVEL9K_CONTEXT_DEFAULT_FOREGROUND='yellow'
  POWERLEVEL9K_BATTERY_CHARGING='yellow'
  POWERLEVEL9K_BATTERY_CHARGED='green'
  POWERLEVEL9K_BATTERY_DISCONNECTED='$DEFAULT_COLOR'
  POWERLEVEL9K_BATTERY_LOW_THRESHOLD='10'
  POWERLEVEL9K_BATTERY_LOW_COLOR='red'
  POWERLEVEL9K_MULTILINE_FIRST_PROMPT_PREFIX=''
  POWERLEVEL9K_BATTERY_ICON='\uf1e6 '
  POWERLEVEL9K_PROMPT_ON_NEWLINE=false
  POWERLEVEL9K_VCS_MODIFIED_BACKGROUND='yellow'
  POWERLEVEL9K_VCS_UNTRACKED_BACKGROUND='yellow'
  POWERLEVEL9K_VCS_UNTRACKED_ICON='?'

  POWERLEVEL9K_LEFT_PROMPT_ELEMENTS=(os_icon context battery dir vcs)
  POWERLEVEL9K_RIGHT_PROMPT_ELEMENTS=(status time)

  POWERLEVEL9K_SHORTEN_DIR_LENGTH=1

  POWERLEVEL9K_TIME_FORMAT="%D{%l:%M %p \uf073 %d %b}"
  POWERLEVEL9K_TIME_BACKGROUND='black'
  POWERLEVEL9K_TIME_FOREGROUND='white'
  POWERLEVEL9K_RAM_BACKGROUND='yellow'
  POWERLEVEL9K_STATUS_VERBOSE=true
  POWERLEVEL9K_STATUS_CROSS=true

  plugins=(git)

  source $ZSH/oh-my-zsh.sh
  ```

Comment: Please post the output of your `~/.zshrc`, as well as the `~/.oh-my-zsh/themes/<name>.zsh-theme` file you're using _(theme being used is set in the `.zshrc`)_

Comment: I have added the `.zshrc` file and I am using the Powerlevel9k theme but I have been facing this issue on all themes. @JW0914

Comment: Please also post the theme file, as the terminal appearance is defined by both.

Comment: Start with `zsh -f` and try to narrow that behaviour down to a specific command/option somewhere in the oh-my-zsh files.

Comment: @JW0914 I have added a link to the theme file from Github. It was too big to include in the question.

Comment: @mpy Using the -f option, It works, i.e. I don't see the problem anymore. But I am not sure on how to proceed. Is there a way to load zsh without loading oh-my-zsh? Maybe oh-my-zsh is what is doing this, 'cause I've tried chaning themes without any results

Comment: @AnishSharma It's not OhMyZsh that's doing it, as it's not the default setting, and is likely due to PowerLevel9K, but that's way too large of a config to figure it out unless knowing roughly where to look and I don't use that theme. To verify, change to a different theme and the issue will likely resolve; if it does,  review/open an [issue](https://github.com/Powerlevel9k/powerlevel9k/issues) _([this](https://github.com/JW0914/oh-my-zsh/blob/master/custom/themes/dallas-custom.zsh-theme) is the theme I use and my [`.zshrc`](https://github.com/JW0914/oh-my-zsh/blob/master/.zshrc))_

Comment: @JW0914 I tried different themes, namely - `agnoster`, `avit` and `bira`. But I am facing the same issue on all of them. Besides I had been facing this issue before I started using PowerLevel9k. I think the theme might not be the problem

Comment: @AnishSharma Something was manually changed in one OhMyZsh's config files that deal with the `PROMPT` variable _(or a prompt variable was modified in `/etc/profile` or equivalent)_, as I use OhMyZsh on all the routers I manage and Linux distros I use and the `echo`-ing of the command within the prompt is not the default. Clone the OhMyZsh repo and start fresh, placing any files you customize (excl. `~/.zshrc`)  into `~/.oh-my-zsh/custom` with the same folder-hierarchy and file naming _(e.g. to customize a theme, copy the `.zsh-theme` file to `~/.oh-my-zsh/custom/themes/<name>.zsh-theme`)_

Comment: @JW0914 Okay I think I found the problem. Removing the line `export TERM=screen-256color` fixes the issue. I am not sure why that line could cause it. I remember adding it ages ago.

Comment: @AnishSharma Try `xterm-256color` in lieu of `screen-256color`. You didn't mention an OS so I never thought about it, but I know with BSD _[FreeBSD, FreeNAS, TrueNAS/TrueOS, possibly MacOS/iOS]_ that could be a result of a setting in the `termcap` config _(on BSD, it's located at `/usr/share/misc/termcap`)_.

Comment: @JW0914 Using `xterm-256color` instead of `screen-256color` works! Thanks. I'm not sure if it's important though. Even without this, I can pretty much print all 256 colors on the terminal. I am using Pop!_OS and was facing the issue on both the default terminal app and Guake.

Comment: Perhaps not related to your problem, but Powerlevel9k has been discontinued: https://github.com/Powerlevel9k/powerlevel9k . You should migrate to Powerlevel10k: https://github.com/romkatv/powerlevel10k

Comment: @AnishSharma Since your problem is solved, can you close the question, please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem was with the `.zshrc` file. Replacing the line -

```
export TERM=screen-256color
```

with -

```
export TERM=xterm-256color
```

Solves the problem.

Comment: You really shouldn't set $TERM manually. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/108410/is-it-correct-to-set-the-term-variable-manually